# How to comment out multiple lines based on specific grep?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, comments

Here is a test file

```
dog
dogcatmoose
case $- in 
      *i*);;
        *) return;;
esac

catmoose
case
esac
dog cat
esac
```

I need to comment out the following:

```
dog
dogcatmoose
#case $- in 
#      *i*);;
#        *) return;;
#esac

catmoose
case
esac
dog cat
esac
```

Notice that ONLY the specific lines were commented out. Note also I need to do this to multiple files and those lines commented out maybe located on different areas of the file. However those lines will always be together. Therefore I cannot comment out with sed based on line numbers.

How can I comment out those lines specifically, which will work on multiple files where that section maybe anywhere in the file. I assume I can grep on `'case $- in'` then comment out that line and all lines UP to the first `esac` instance after `'case $- in'`.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Are those lines always preceded by `dogcatmoose` and followed by `catmoose`? If so, then just use `awk` and flip a variable that controls comment character generation on and off based on those words.

Comment: For a precise match of the text block, line by line (regardless preceding and following lines), you could (again) use `awk` or the like and implement a simple state automaton incremented as the matched lines go by. Reaching the end of the automaton prints out the lines, commented out. A mismatch switches the automaton back to its initial state and all states encountered thus far are printed out, uncommented. (Which also applies to the trivial case of a non-matching line at the initial state.)

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek Correction, there is a blank line after every `esac` so that can be a match variable.

Comment: The rules to determine the lines to be commented out are unclear.

Comment: I think I found a solution with `awk`, the following will comment out `case $- in` then all lines up to first blank line. `awk '/^case\ \$\-\ in/{f=1} !NF{f=0} f{$0="#" $0} 1' /home/mruser/myfile` but this does not actually edit the file. It only shows the output of what I want, how can I make awk edit the file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, then you could use a [`sed` range address](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Range-Addresses) to comment out that region:

```bash
$ sed '/case $- in/,/esac/ s/^/# /' <<\TEXT
dog
dogcatmoose
case $- in
      *i*);;
        *) return;;
esac

catmoose
case
esac
dog cat
esac
TEXT
```

Output:

```
dog
dogcatmoose
# case $- in
#       *i*);;
#         *) return;;
# esac

catmoose
case
esac
dog cat
esac
```

And, of course, you can do it in-place:

```bash
$ sed -i.back '/case $- in/,/esac/ s/^/# /' target.sh
$
$ tail target.sh target.sh.back 
==> target.sh <==
# case $- in
#       *i*);;
#         *) return;;
# esac

catmoose
case
esac
dog cat
esac

==> target.sh.back <==
case $- in
      *i*);;
        *) return;;
esac

catmoose
case
esac
dog cat
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out a solution with `awk`

```
awk '/^case\ \$\-\ in/{f=1} !NF{f=0} f{$0="#" $0} 1'  /home/mruser/myfile > /home/mruser/.myfile_awk && mv -f /home/mruser/.myfile_awk /home/mruser/myfile
```

- use awk and match on `case $- in`
- comment out that line.
- comment out all lines after that line up to first blank line. Do not comment out the blank line
- send output to a temp file called `.myfile_awk`
- move the temp file to the other files place

This seems to work, albite a bit hacky. If anyone else has a better alternative please share.

Comment: GNU `awk` can edit files in-place; the strange syntax is `awk -i inplace` (as if `inplace` was an include file).

Comment: I am aware. The system does not use GNU awk, have to do it this way I think :(

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek `inplace` **is** an include file. In gawk `-i` means "include" to include a library, in this case the inplace-editing library.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the line numbers are always 3-6, you can also use...

```
sed -i '3,6s/^/# /g' file
```

Comment: I specifically stated in my post that I cannot use line numbers.